# How to increase a column's height in a css grid without increasing the parent row's height or sibling column's heights

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, grid-layout, semantic-ui

I am using semantic-ui's grid, which is a sixteen column grid system. Initially, I am displaying multiple rows containing two eight-wide columns each. All of the columns are initially an equal height.

When initially rendering all of the columns, the user will see something that looks like this -- where each line is a row, and each column is a letter:

```
a b
c d
e f
g h
```

There is a user interaction that increases the height of a selected column. So if increasing the height of 'a', for example, the current behavior after increasing height will render something that looks like this:

```
a b
a .
a .
a .
c d
e f
g h
```

The increased height of 'a' will increase its row height so that the bottom of 'b' is above the bottom of 'a'. The columns in the bottom (last) row will always be aligned (unless increasing the height of 'g' or 'h', which are the bottom).

The desired behavior that I would like after increasing height of column 'a':

```
a b
a d
a f 
a h
c 
e 
g
```

In other words, from a user's perspective for this case I'd like to push everything in the first column down but leave everything in the second column the same.

As I said, I am using semantic-ui so answers in relation to that would be great, but I am not sure how I would do this with bootstrap or other grid systems.

I am not interested in using jQuery Masonry. Perhaps thinking in terms of a grid layout for this is not correct, but I am curious if anyone has solved this problem in any simple ways that aren't coming to mind.

Here is a demo on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ne64wkmm/1/

Comment: Got a minimal demo? This just sounds like you need to adjust the equal height default setting.

Comment: Sure @Paulie_D, I just made one and updated the question to include the link.

Comment: Well the obvious solution is to load them in a different order...rather than have a row with two columns, have two columns instead without the rows. Other than that, yes, Masonry is the answer..unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your obvious solution? Any column can dynamically be given a larger height after the page has loaded via a click event. My jsfiddle didn't show this, it only showed the case of 'a' already having the expanded state.